# Delete a discord message with Webhook C#

Tags: c#

How can I delete a discord message with a Webhook? I already added a Webhook send message but I cant find out how to delete the messages that the Webhook sent without opening the app and deleting it manually.

Comment: hi, not sure if this option would work for you https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2465

Comment: Are you using a library like [Discord.net](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DSharpPlus library, the process of deleting a message from a Webhook is very simple!

Just store the value that the method `ExecuteAsync();` returns in a variable and then use the method `DeleteAsync();`

As in this code:

```cs
//Here I am creating a Webhook that will send the message "Message to Delete"
DiscordWebhookBuilder WebhookSample = new DiscordWebhookBuilder
{
    Username = "Username",
    Content = "Message to Delete",
};

//Here I am getting the bot's main webhook in the current channel
DiscordWebhook currentChannelWebhook = await ctx.Channel.CreateWebhookAsync("Sample");

//Here I make the Webhook send a message and save the value
Task<DiscordMessage> result = await currentChannelWebhook.ExecuteAsync(WebhookSample);

//And finally, I delete the message sent 
await result.DeleteAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Discord.Net then deleting a message is handled pretty easily like this:

```
var sent = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Hello world!");
await sent.DeleteAsync();
```